# How to replace double backslash in a JSON text?

Tags: json, jq

I've got this json file:

```
{
    "module": {
        "data": {
            "orderInfo_203759231000": {
                "fields": {
                    "createdAt": "Dipesan pada\\r\\n 17 Mei 2018",
                    "tradeOrderId": 203759231000
                }
            },
            "orderInfo_203759231000": {
                "fields": {
                    "createdAt": "Dipesan pada\\r\\n 22 Mei 2018",
                    "tradeOrderId": 203759231000
                }
            },
            "orderInfo_203759231000": {
                "fields": {
                    "createdAt": "Dipesan pada\\r\\n 22 Mei 2018",
                    "tradeOrderId": 203759231000
                }
            },
            "orderInfo_203759231000": {
                "fields": {
                    "createdAt": "Dipesan pada\\r\\n 22 Mei 2018",
                    "tradeOrderId": 203759231000
                }
            },
            "orderInfo_203759231000": {
                "fields": {
                    "createdAt": "Dipesan pada\\r\\n 22 Mei 2018",
                    "tradeOrderId": 203759231000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to remove `Dipesan pada\\r\\n` here's what I have tried:

```
sed 's/Dipesan pada \\\\r\\\\n//g' file.json
```

But it doesn't work, I want the end result to only be the dates like this:

```
"createdAt": "17 Mei 2018",
"createdAt": "22 Mei 2018",
"createdAt": "22 Mei 2018",
etc...
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Why would you want to parse JSON with `sed`. Install a proper JSON parser `jq`. Also fix your json input, it seems to be syntactically incorrect - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I've already got `jq` installed but I don't know how to replace half of a value with `jq` if you know then by all means teach me

Comment: Will do, but fix your JSON input, all your keys are duplicated - orderInfo_203759231000

Comment: I changed that for security purposes, you can change the numbers to whatever you want

Comment: sorry I just copied and pasted everything, too lazy to differentiate every key lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backslashes are fine, congratulations! The issue is with the placement of a single pesky space:

```
sed 's/Dipesan pada \\\\r\\\\n//g' file.json # bad
sed 's/Dipesan pada\\\\r\\\\n //g' file.json # good
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq` with [update operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment) and [sub](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) filter, you can do it as below. The slashes need to escaped twice to make it work

```
jq '(.module.data[].fields.createdAt)|=(sub("Dipesan pada\\\\r\\\\n ";""))' input.json
```

As tested on [jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/-jl_7ERLpe). This is tested on your JSON input with keys modified to avoid duplication.